# Raspbian Jessie: udev not triggering when I plug in my usb device

Tags: raspbian, udev

I am attempting to run some code (preferably in a script) whenever I plug in my keyboard to my Raspberry Pi. I currently have Rasbian Jessie installed on it (probably the latest version?). I found through my research that I should use "udev" to trigger events when usb devices get plugged into a Linux machine.

Just to test this out I want it to open up a browser whenever I plugin my keyboard (the command it's trying to run does work in a terminal on the raspberry pi with my monitor plugged in). I've created the following file `/etc/udev/rules.d/keyboard.rules`:

`ACTION=="add",ATTRS{idVendor}=="413c",RUN+="epiphany --display=:0 http://www.google.com"`

I got the idVendor from the `lsusb` command: `Bus 001 Device 027: ID 413c:2105 Dell Computer Corp. Model L100 Keyboard`

But when I unplug & plug back in my keyboard nothing happens.

What else I've tried:

- Restarting the Raspberry Pi
- Running the command `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules`
- Running the command `sudo udevadm control --reload`
- Having the keyboard.rules try and run a script `RUN+='/home/pi/test.sh'` (which has been setup to be runnable).
- Checking the different "desktops" (hitting Crl+Alt+F1 - F12) (though only F1 (console) and F7 (gui desktop) are active).
- Verifying the idVendor by running `udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/input/event0)` (which gives me all of the ATTRS for the keyboard)
- Verifying that udev is seeing the "add" even come in by running `udevadm monitor` & `udevadm monitor --property` as I'm plugging in the keyboard
- Testing it with `udevadm test $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/input/event0)`. This displays the following information:

```
    calling: test
    version 215
    This program is for debugging only, it does not run any program
    specified by a RUN key. It may show incorrect results, because
    some values may be different, or not available at a simulation run.

    load module index
    Network interface NamePolicy= disabled on kernel commandline, ignoring.
    timestamp of '/etc/systemd/network' changed
    timestamp of '/lib/systemd/network' changed
    Parsed configuration file /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
    Created link configuration context.
    timestamp of '/etc/udev/rules.d' changed
    timestamp of '/lib/udev/rules.d' changed
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/10-local-rpi.rules
    read rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/40-scratch.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/42-usb-hid-pm.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-bluetooth-hci-auto-poweron.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-firmware.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/55-dm.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-cdrom_id.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-crda.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-drm.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-fuse.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-gnupg.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-keyboard.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libgphoto2-6.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libpisock9.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-alsa.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-serial.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-dm.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-tape.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-v4l.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/60-triggerhappy.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/61-accelerometer.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/64-btrfs.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/64-xorg-xkb.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-power-switch.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/70-uaccess.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/71-seat.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-idrac.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/73-seat-late.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-net-description.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-probe_mtd.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/75-tty-description.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/78-sound-card.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-drivers.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-networking.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-udisks.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-udisks2.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-hdparm.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-hwclock.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/85-regulatory.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/90-alsa-restore.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-udev-late.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/95-wedo.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/97-hid2hci.rules
    read rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/99-com.rules
    read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules
    read rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/keyboard.rules
    read rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/test.rules
    rules contain 393216 bytes tokens (32768 * 12 bytes), 23387 bytes strings
    23799 strings (190642 bytes), 21572 de-duplicated (169483 bytes), 2228 trie nodes used
    IMPORT builtin 'input_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:10
    capabilities/ev raw kernel attribute: 120013
    capabilities/abs raw kernel attribute: 0
    capabilities/rel raw kernel attribute: 0
    capabilities/key raw kernel attribute: 10000 7 ff9f207a c14057ff febeffdf ffefffff ffffffff fffffffe
    test_key: checking bit block 0 for any keys; found=1
    test_key: checking bit block 32 for any keys; found=1
    test_key: checking bit block 64 for any keys; found=1
    test_key: checking bit block 96 for any keys; found=1
    test_key: checking bit block 128 for any keys; found=1
    test_key: checking bit block 160 for any keys; found=1
    test_key: checking bit block 192 for any keys; found=1
    test_key: checking bit block 224 for any keys; found=1
    GROUP 101 /lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:29
    IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-keyboard.rules:12
    IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' returned non-zero
    IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-keyboard.rules:20
    IMPORT builtin 'hwdb' returned non-zero
    IMPORT builtin 'usb_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules:7
    /sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0: if_class 3 protocol 0
    LINK 'input/by-id/usb-Dell_Dell_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules:24
    IMPORT builtin 'path_id' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules:31
    LINK 'input/by-path/platform-3f980000.usb-usb-0:1.2:1.0-event-kbd' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-input.rules:33
    RUN '/usr/sbin/th-cmd --socket /var/run/thd.socket --passfd --udev' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-triggerhappy.rules:4
    GROUP 101 /etc/udev/rules.d/99-com.rules:1
    MODE 0660 /etc/udev/rules.d/99-com.rules:1
    RUN 'epiphany --display=:0 http://www.google.com' /etc/udev/rules.d/keyboard.rules:1
    handling device node '/dev/input/event0', devnum=c13:64, mode=0660, uid=0, gid=101
    preserve permissions /dev/input/event0, 020660, uid=0, gid=101
    preserve already existing symlink '/dev/char/13:64' to '../input/event0'
    found 'c13:64' claiming '/run/udev/links/\x2finput\x2fby-id\x2fusb-Dell_Dell_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd'
    creating link '/dev/input/by-id/usb-Dell_Dell_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd' to '/dev/input/event0'
    preserve already existing symlink '/dev/input/by-id/usb-Dell_Dell_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd' to '../event0'
    found 'c13:64' claiming '/run/udev/links/\x2finput\x2fby-path\x2fplatform-3f980000.usb-usb-0:1.2:1.0-event-kbd'
    creating link '/dev/input/by-path/platform-3f980000.usb-usb-0:1.2:1.0-event-kbd' to '/dev/input/event0'
    preserve already existing symlink '/dev/input/by-path/platform-3f980000.usb-usb-0:1.2:1.0-event-kbd' to '../event0'
    unable to create temporary db file '/run/udev/data/c13:64.tmp': Permission denied
    .INPUT_CLASS=kbd
    ACTION=add
    BACKSPACE=guess
    DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-id/usb-Dell_Dell_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd /dev/input/by-path/platform-3f980000.usb-usb-0:1.2:1.0-event-kbd
    DEVNAME=/dev/input/event0
    DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:413C:2105.0014/input/input23/event0
    ID_BUS=usb
    ID_INPUT=1
    ID_INPUT_KEY=1
    ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD=1
    ID_MODEL=Dell_USB_Keyboard
    ID_MODEL_ENC=Dell\x20USB\x20Keyboard
    ID_MODEL_ID=2105
    ID_PATH=platform-3f980000.usb-usb-0:1.2:1.0
    ID_PATH_TAG=platform-3f980000_usb-usb-0_1_2_1_0
    ID_REVISION=0352
    ID_SERIAL=Dell_Dell_USB_Keyboard
    ID_TYPE=hid
    ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
    ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030101:
    ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
    ID_VENDOR=Dell
    ID_VENDOR_ENC=Dell
    ID_VENDOR_ID=413c
    MAJOR=13
    MINOR=64
    SUBSYSTEM=input
    USEC_INITIALIZED=78790607
    XKBLAYOUT=us
    XKBMODEL=pc105
    XKBOPTIONS=terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
    XKBVARIANT=
    run: '/usr/sbin/th-cmd --socket /var/run/thd.socket --passfd --udev'
    run: 'epiphany --display=:0 http://www.google.com'
    unload module index
    Unloaded link configuration context.
```

Which if you scroll down to the bottom you see `run: 'epiphany --display=:0 http://www.google.com'`. Which makes me believe that it should work.

But when I unplug & plug my keyboard back in nothing happens....

I haven't been able to get `udevadm trigger` to do anything (tried multiple paths and other inputs, but it just returns nothing).

Are there some sort of logs that I can check to see if it's trying to run my command/script? Is there another way to monitor this script? Is there another way to test this script so I can actually see it run without actually plugging in a usb device?

Comment: I've created a script controller_retropi.sh that has the following:

Comment: I've created a script controller_retropi.sh that has the following:
`#!/bin/sh
epiphany --display=:0 http://www.google.com`
(chowning it to 777 so that it can run)

I've updated my `keyboard.rules` to now be:
`ACTION=="add",ATTRS{idVendor}=="413c",RUN+="/bin/bash /home/pi/scripts/controller_retropi.sh &"`

I've re-ran the `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules` to refresh the rules and double checked they were loaded with `udevadmin test $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/input/event0)`.

Still no luck.

Comment: I've also figured out how to use trigger with `sudo udevadm trigger -v -c add -a idVendor=413c`. And i see the device pop up, and see it when I monitor it. But the RUN command still is not being triggered.....

Answer (score 1):

> Are there some sort of logs that I can check to see if it's trying to run my command/script? Is there another way to monitor this script?

After finding [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36251/in-which-log-should-i-check-for-udev-errors) thread I found you could see the udev logs in the system log file found in the `/var/log/syslog` file. This will show only the errors by default, but if you bump the log level up to "debug" you'll be able to see everything. I first ran `udevadm control --log-priority=debug` and updated the `/etc/udev/udev.conf` file to "debug".

What I found was that when I plugged in my keyboard the system would throw the following error:

`failed to execute '/lib/udev/epiphany --display=:0 http://www.google.com': No such file or directory`.

Ah-Ha it seems like it was trying to run epiphany from the /lib/udev folder. So I updated the code again to run the correct file path to epiphany: `/usr/bin/epiphany --display=:0 http://www.google.com`. But I then got the following error:

```
Feb 19 13:44:10 raspberrypi systemd-udevd[6473]: '/usr/bin/epiphany --display=:0 http://www.google.com'(err) 'No protocol specified'
Feb 19 13:44:10 raspberrypi systemd-udevd[6473]: '/usr/bin/epiphany --display=:0 http://www.google.com'(err) 'Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused'
Feb 19 13:44:10 raspberrypi systemd-udevd[6473]: '/usr/bin/epiphany --display=:0 http://www.google.com'(out) 'Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display: :0'
Feb 19 13:44:10 raspberrypi systemd-udevd[6473]: '/usr/bin/epiphany --display=:0 http://www.google.com' [6479] exit with return code 1
```

This code works correctly if I paste it directly into a terminal so it was odd that it couldn't find the display... Eventually I figured out that udev runs everything as "root". Which apparently "root" does not have access to the displays. When I run the command through the terminal it uses the user "pi" which does have access to the displays. So the final edit to the command: `/sbin/runuser -l pi -c '/usr/bin/epiphany --display=:0 http://www.google.com'`. AND IT WORKS!

Current small hiccup is it opens 2 browsers, but I think that's just because I'm only checking the "idVendor" and the usb device has quite a few children that share that "idVendor". So when the single keyboard gets plugged in it see multiple usb devices and run the udev rule multiple times.

> Is there another way to test this script so I can actually see it run
>   without actually plugging in a usb device?

I mentioned this in the comments above, but I found you could run the following command to trigger the udev command without having to un-plug & plug back in the keyboard: `sudo udevadm trigger -v -c add -a idVendor=413c`